# How to represent bi-grams

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, cluster-analysis, text-mining

I'm working on a system/algorithm that will detect topics in a stream of tweets.

What I'll do is remove the stop words, emoticons, urls, etc. and I'm thinking about representing the tweet as follows:

```
terms = (t1, t2, ..., tk)
hashtags = (h1, h2, ..., hn)
date = date of tweet
```

and then use some similarity measures between the tweets when applying some clustering algorithms, combining those 3 values. This will be a little more complex than that, since I'll handle replies (eg. when you reply to some tweet, most of the time you keep talking about the same topics, etc).

I don't know if that will work or not, but the problem I'm seeing so far is that I'm not identifying **n-grams**, so *Barack Obama* appear most of time together, and in my system it will be two separate terms (*Barack* and *Obama*).

My question is:

**How can I also represent bi-grams? I mean, how is it usually modeled?**

I thought about having something like the following:

```
Tweet = `Some words here`
terms = `[some, words, here, some words, words here]`
...
```

but I don't know if that is the correct way to go, if I have to do that for every possible bi-gram, etc.

**Edit**:

In my database, I will have all the terms stored. Should I also store the bi-grams as if they were terms?

Comment: What is the question -- how to generate bigrams (which has been answered many times before on this site), or how to find relevant bigrams?

Comment: `NLTK` represents a bigram simply as a `tuple`. If that's your question...

Comment: @larsmans **how to represent them**. I'd be also interested in how to find relevant ones, but that's another question. My question is **How to represent the bigrams?** as if they were simple terms? See my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say one of your documents is "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".

the bi-grams and uni-grams would be:

```
the_quick
quick_brown
brown_fox
fox_jumped
jumped_over
over_the
the_lazy
lazy_dog
the
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
lazy
dog
```

You could then put all the unique grams of all of your documents in a word vector to analyze, like this:

```
Document the_quick  quick_brown  ... lazy  dog   some_other_gram

1        0.01       0.02             0.1   0.05  0.0
2        0          0                0.12  0.0   0.1
3        0.5        0.4              0     0     0
```

where the numbers in the cells represent the count, binary count, frequency, or TFIDF score of the terms in the documents.

You could then compare documents for similarity, or do clustering, or classification on them.

Comment: hmm.. I already know what bi-grams are. It doesn't seem to help me too much.

Comment: You asked how to represent bi-grams, and I showed you. You put an underscore between the two terms.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought you were extracting the bigrams of the text. So, I should store then `the_quick` as if it was a term in my database, and include it in the vector of terms when clustering, etc?

Comment: yes, "quick_brown" is essentially another term in your document. It would be a column in a table that you are analyzing, the same as "fox" would be. You can then calculate the frequencies for that "term", do correlations, use it for clustering or classification.